# Replacing texts when clicking on image

Tags: jquery, html, image, replacewith

Having an issue where the texts in the header does not change when i click on the respective images. Was intended purpose is to replace the text. Or hide and show the respective texts.

EDIT:

Thanks for the src=' ' tips guys. However, it only worked once for the change, and the .byline doesn't change.

```
$("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg']").click(function(){
    $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header1</h1>" );
    $('.byline').replaceWith( "<span>line1</span>" );
});

$("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg']").click(function(){
    $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header22</h1>" );
    $('.byline').replaceWith( "<span>line22</span>" );
});

$("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/139.jpg']").click(function(){
    $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header333</h1>" );
    $('.byline').replaceWith( "<span>line333</span>" );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbezfh3w/2/

Comment: try `img[src="http://..."]` as your selector

Comment: Try my updated code... byline will change..

Comment: thank you haxxxxxxxxxxxxton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with your selector. your selector should be  `img[src="url"]`

Try this updated code:

```
$('.imageCS').hover(function()
    {
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.3},500);
    }, function()

    {   
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:1},1000)
    });

    $("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg']").click(function(){
        $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header1</h1>" );
        $('.title span').replaceWith( "<span>line1</span>" );
    });

    $("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg']").click(function(){
        $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header22</h1>" );
        $('.title span').replaceWith( "<span>line22</span>" );
    });

    $("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/139.jpg']").click(function(){
        $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header333</h1>" );
        $('.title span').replaceWith( "<span>line333</span>" );
    });
```

Comment: hey bilal,i've an issue with  "h1"  as well. it doesnt work when i use '.highlights h1'

Comment: let me take a look

Comment: SORRY Bilal, i sould be using title too, i've found the issue

Comment: its the similar solution to what you gave, thank you again bilal. How do I rep?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg']").click(function(){
    $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header1</h1>" );
    $('.byline').replaceWith( "<span>line1</span>" );
});

$("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg']").click(function(){
    $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header22</h1>" );
    $('.byline').replaceWith( "<span>line22</span>" );
});

$("img[src='http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/139.jpg']").click(function(){
    $( "h1" ).replaceWith( "<h1>header333</h1>" );
    $('.byline').replaceWith( "<span>line333</span>" );
});
```